# Compile deodexed app from aosp

Tags: build, android-source

I'm trying to build a deodexed application from aosp and it works like it was said here [CyanogenMod or AOSP: Compile a single project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057394/cyanogenmod-or-aosp-compile-a-single-project) .
But `mmm` outputs odexed app, is there any option to build it deodexed? Also i've included my app in build and when make entire aosp using options `DISABLE_DEXPREOPT=true` and `WITH_DEXPREOPT=false` it outputs normal deodexed apk, but it takes too much time to rebuild the entire project every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look in `Android.mk` and find module name in `LOCAL_MODULE := %module_name%` and then execute command `make %module_name% DISABLE_DEXPREOPT=true WITH_DEXPREOPT=false`.

Comment: When I run this, the only difference is it doesn't create the .odex file. But the .apk file is the same whether I compile it normally or deodexed, so maybe this isn't necessary?

Comment: @bmaupin you are right, it isn't necessary in general. I was working with ROM modifications, so it was convenient for specific task.

Answer (score 0):

To go through Deodexing:
Simply add to `Android.mk`

```
LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT := false
```